# RabbitMQ How to consume a message with all .net core instances in a nginx cluster in order to update cache?

Tags: .net-core, caching, rabbitmq

I have 3 instances of a .NET Core app in a nginx cluster. Is there a way to synchronize all instances in order to have the same InMemoryCache?
The trigger for this update is made through rabbit but only the first instance that consumes the message will have the cache updated.

The reason I don't want to use Redis or Sql Server Cache is because InMemoryCache is faster.

Comment: You can create a cluster with the three nodes: https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/clustering